# UITableViewCell has a UILabel inside,how to make the Label response

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
    [cell.textView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:@selector(labelClick)]]; // textView is a UILabel
```

if i select the cell,it may be call didselect method first,so the label can't be response.
My purpose is that when i click the label,it will do something,and the tableView won't show me the selected style.

Comment: instead of UILabel use UIButton. Just give it a try?

Comment: try cell.textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Use UITapGestureRecognizer instead of UIPanGestureRecognizer,like this:-

```
 [cell.textView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelClick)]];
```

and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: do this to deselect the tableviewcell

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your did select method add following code

```
YourCell *cell = (YourCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

It will make your cell not to highlight on selection.

Also add following code for your label

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(youraction:)];
[tap setDelegate:self];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[yourLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap]
```

Comment: It will be more better to setSelectionStlye in CellForRowAtIndexPath